# How to eliminate the space after section when baselineskip has been used?

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, baseline

I apologize if this question has been asked before, I searched the site I found some similar questions but didn't exactly find this.

I would like to eliminate the space after the section title. This can be normally done by the package `titlesec`.
The problem is that I use `baselineskip` and this prevent `titlesec` package to completely eliminate this space. A solution without using `titlesec` is also welcomed.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{2\baselineskip}
\section{section}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the third argument of the `\titlespacing` command of titlesec with negative values

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{-0.5\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{2\baselineskip}
\section{section}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Setting double linespaces like you do is not recommended however if I'm not mistaken. An alternative way is using the setspace package and putting `\doublespacing` in the preamble.

Comment: Let me add that `doublespacing` is *not*, as one might naively think doubling \baselineskip, because of optical effects of blank spaces. Actually, it multiplies by `1.667`, `1.618` or `1.655`, depending on the font size of the document.

Comment: Good to know, I took a peek in the source (there is no proper documentation for some reason...) and you can use the `\setstrech` command for arbitrary spacing. So `\setstrech{2}` would do the job if `\doublespacing` is truly not sufficient.

Comment: Generally, it is recommended  to use `setspace`, which takes care of lists, footnotes and a few other things. See more information in `l2tabu`.

Comment: Many thanks, I would like that the space before the section to not being changed. Is it the case with your solution?